# Prestashop - How to override another module in own module

Tags: php, module, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I create own module. This module should override the BlockCart class.

I created a file /mymodule/override/blockcart/blockcart.php but this file is not executed.

I can not place this file in / override because the module must work on several shops and the instalation must works.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your file in the right path of your module:

`mymodule/override/modules/blockcart/blockcart.php`

Then your `blockcart.php` should be like this:

```
class BlockCartOverride extends BlockCart
{
    /* your stuff */
}
```

During the installation PrestaShop install your override.

Useful link:
- [How to override modules](http://build.prestashop.com/howtos/module/how-to-override-modules/)

Comment: Thanks, works! I forgot about  mymodule/override/ **modules** /blockcart/blockcart.php in my path and I didn't see it.